# Insert QWidget to an existing QBoxLayout at a particular position?

Tags: qt, qwidget

The questions says it all. Say I have a layout

```
mylayout
|-- widgetA
`-- widgetB
```

How do I insert a new widget to this tree?

```
mylayout
|-- widgetA
|-- widgetC
`-- widgetB
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `QBoxLayout::insertWidget`.

The index is zero-based,
it means the number of the widget before which the new one will be inserted.
Or, you can think of it as  what the index of the inserted item will become.

In this particular case you have:

```
layout.addWidget(widgetA)
layout.addWidget(widgetB)

layout.insertWidget(1, widgetC)
```